# SSRS report with second paramater that allows null is not working

Tags: reporting-services, isnull

I have a report with 2 date parameters and 2 parameters: `@ConstitID` and `@BatchID` that both allow `Null`.

The report was working as expected until I added the second parameter `@BatchID`.

Q: Could someone explain what I am missing in the code below? I will be looking to add additional parameters that will allow `Null` and need to clearly understand how to add additional parameters that allow `Null`.

```
WHERE (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd)
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = @ConstitID)
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.batch_id = @BatchID) OR (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd)
AND (@ConstitID IS NULL) OR (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id IS NULL)
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.batch_id IS NULL) OR (@BatchID IS NULL)
ORDER BY p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to resolve the issue by deleting 2 filters that I had set up in SSRS based on the parameters @BatchID and @ConstitID. I then tided up the code as follows and the report works as expected. (I tried to post this as a comment first as I am interested to know if there is a more efficient coding solution.

```
WHERE (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart    
AND @TransactionDateEnd)
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = @ConstitID)
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.batch_id = @BatchID) OR (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date BETWEEN  @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd) 
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.batch_id = @BatchID)
AND (@ConstitID IS NULL) OR (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd)
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_payment.constit_id = @ConstitID)
AND (@BatchID IS NULL) OR (p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number IN (@FeeGL_Number))
AND (p_memb_fee_batch_header.fin_tran_date BETWEEN @TransactionDateStart AND @TransactionDateEnd)
AND (@ConstitID IS NULL)
AND (@BatchID IS NULL)
ORDER BY p_memb_fee_batch_pmt_dst.fee_gl_number
```